# Sometimes-but-not-always tiny font via VNC?

Tags: debian, fonts, vnc

I'm using `tightvncserver` on a Debian 7.8 to access the machine from Windows. The Windows machine has a 4K resolution, so I've manually set the `-geometry` to be quite large. The first couple times I launched the server and connected, the font size looked quite normal, but then I started getting a really tiny (not quite unreadable but very aggravating) font size upon connecting.

Incidentally, I have commented out the `xsession` call in `~/.vnv/xstartup` and instead am launching my window manager (`i3`) directly. At first I used `i3 &`, but although that worked initially I sometimes saw a grey-hatch-pattern and nothing else upon connecting, so I removed the `&`. (I don't quite understand why it would make any difference, since that's the end of the startup script, but...there you have it.)

(Note: I thought I'd seen a similar question on AskUbuntu, but now I can't seem to find it.)

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly specifying `-dpi 96` when launching tightvncserver seems to be a reasonable workaround.

However, this makes the fonts appear somewhat fuzzy on my screen.

Comment: Run `xdpyinfo | grep resolution` to find out what resolution your X server actually has, and use that instead of 96.

Comment: @lcd047 Doesn't that just return the resolution it's running with? What extra information does it provide? I don't think that actually implies anything about what the "correct" resolution should be.

Comment: You're supposed to run `xdpyinfo` in a terminal, not in vnc.  If your X server thinks it's running at, say, 115 DPI, and you're forcing vnc to run at 96 DPI, you'll have fuzzy fonts.  This is especially visible on LCD screens.

Comment: @lcd047 It appears that `xdpyinfo` tries to use the `DISPLAY` variable unless you specify `-display` in the command. My local display, `:0`, is at 96 dpi, but I expect that's because that's the connected-monitor's native res. (It's not a great monitor.) The vnc server display is also at 96 dpi--is this not determined by the command used to start the server, though?